# String joined with multiple variables are not executing in setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, html, dom

String joined with single variable is executing properly in setTimeout() function

```
setTimeout("document.getElementById('err_box').innerHTML = "+selected_troops.length, 1000);
```

But when I join multiple variable in same string. It is not executing.

```
setTimeout("document.getElementById('err_box').innerHTML = "+selected_troops.length+" Men "+varues, 1000);
```

And this is also not executing ("string"+variable+"string")

```
setTimeout("document.getElementById('err_box').innerHTML = "+selected_troops.length+" Men", 1000);
```

Comment: You technically should pass a function into the `setTimeout` function, followed by a number. However, a workaround for your scenario would be to execute this `setTimeout("document.getElementById('err_box').innerHTML = +selected_troops.length+ 'Men' +varues", 1000);`, which wraps the entire callback in a string, which would be executed 1 second later. This works because there is no scope-specific syntax here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should be doing,

```
setTimeout(function(){
     document.getElementById('err_box').innerHTML = selected_troops.length+" Men "+varues;
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass functions to `setTimeout()`, not strings:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('err_box').innerHTML = 
    selected_troops.length+" Men";
}, 1000);
```

Your code wasn't working because you didn't account for the fact that the string constants would need to be "double quoted" in order to work. That's really not the right way to do it anyway, however; it's much easier to avoid having to put JavaScript code into JavaScript strings.